# resharper caret position after delete

Tags: ide, editor, resharper

When I press the delete key in Resharper, the caret stays where it was.

I'm looking for an option or key combination that will place the caret position at the end of the current line after a delete. I know Resharper knows how to do this but I can't seem to find it.

Cheers

Comment: @Adrian - should I do that after I press the "Delete" key?? :--)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Resharper the feature doesn't exist (I was sure I'd used it in a prior release - oh well)

Hello Berryl
ReSharper 4.5 doesn't support this at the moment. Thank you!

Andrey Serebryansky
Support Engineer
JetBrains, Inc

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [charts](http://www.pureux.com/pureux/file.axd?file=2009%2f2%2fresharper_keyboard_shortcuts.zip) of Resharper shortcuts... didn't see what you're looking for though :/

Comment: Thanks for those, they are useful.